# Executing parallel and sequential TestNG tests in one run

Tags: automated-testing, testng

We have a group of tests that can be run in parallel and a group of tests that can only be run sequentially.

I would like TestNG to execute all of them in one run but schedule sequential tests sequentially, and parallel tests in parallel. How I can achieve that with TestNG?

I considered the following:

1. Define two test groups with `@Test(group='parallel-tests')` and `@Test(group='sequential-tests')` annotations and run each group separately with proper configuration. I don't like it because I wanted to execute both groups in one run.
2. Create testng.xml file with two suites:

   ```
   <suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >    
     <test name="ParallelGroup" parallel="classes" >
       <classes>
           <class name="testngtests.TestParallel"/>
       </classes>
     </test>    
     <test name="Sequential" parallel="false"  >
       <classes>
           <class name="testngtests.copy.TestSeq"></class>
       </classes>
     </test>
   </suite>
   ```

but then I will need to explcitly list classes or packages of tests to include.

A solution would be to combine both approaches, i.e., something like

```
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
  <test name="ParallelGroup" parallel="classes" >
    <test-group ref="parallel-tests" />
  </test>

  <test name="Sequential" parallel="false"  >
    <test-group ref="sequential-tests" />
  </test>
</suite>
```

but I see no way to reference to test groups in testng.xml, there's nothing like `test-group ref` in TestNG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestNG has many combinations for classes, packages, methods...
For the groups you can use:

```
<test name="Test Suite">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="Test Group1"/>
                <include name="Test Group2"/>
            </run>
        </groups>
</test>
```